# How to add field to Mongoose Schema via route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm using mongodb and mongoose to manage database in my application. As backend I use NodeJS. In my case I have to collect data from some devices. The no of devices are dynamically changing. How can I add schema field via route. My schema is,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dataStructure = mongoose.Schema({
data: [{
    Node_1: [{
        sensor_1: { type: Number },
        sensor_2: { type: Number },
        sensor_3: { type: Number },
        sensor_4: { type: Number }
        }]
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', dataStructure);
```

As in this schema, I have `data` array to store data. If I have 2 Nodes, I want do add `Node_2` to my schema to log data from both 2 nodes. In some cases I want to log data from 3 different Nodes, like that I need to change schema from **client side**. I need to do this from client side,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dataStructure = mongoose.Schema({
data: [{
    Node_1: [{
        sensor_1: { type: Number },
        sensor_2: { type: Number },
        sensor_3: { type: Number },
        sensor_4: { type: Number }
        }],
    Node_2: [{
        sensor_1: { type: Number },
        sensor_2: { type: Number },
        sensor_3: { type: Number },
        sensor_4: { type: Number }
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', dataStructure);
```

How can I do it.

I tried this route,

```
const dynamic_schemas = require('mongoose-dynamic-schemas');

const Data = require('../schema/dataschema');

router.post('/addNode', (req, res, next) => {
    const nodeNumber = req.body.nodeNumber;
    Data
        .then(result => {
        dynamic_schemas.addSchemaField(Data.data, "Node_"+nodeNumber, 
                [{ 
                sensor_1: Number, sensor_2: Number, sensor_3: Number, 
                sensor_4: Number 
                }] )
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if(err){
                res.status(500).json({
                    state: false
                })
            } else{
                res.status(200).json({
                    state: true
                })
            }
    })
 })
```

I'm getting error that saying `Cannot overwrite 'Data' model once compiled.`

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Your schema doesn't seem very flexible.   It would be better to create a schema where you can freely add nodes and sensors based on your needs.   Also your question is very broad.  what have you tried already. please publish all of your code.

Comment: I just need to add a Node in to my data array from client side. It means when I use this system in different place I have to change no of Nodes. So I'm asking how can I change no of nodes in data array. Why are you saying this question is very board.

Comment: Broad, because you didn't provide any feedback/code on what you already tried. other than providing a schema.  I already answered, that the way you are trying to do things is not the way it should be done.  check the documentation on subdocuments in mongoose for an idea of how things can be done.

Comment: I edited my question with code that I tried. I used **mongoose-dynamic-schemas** npm package for it.